# ASP.NET Accessing cookie value in session_end event of global.asax

Tags: asp.net, cookies, global-asax

In ASP.NET , How can i retrieve  a cookie value in the Session_End event of global.asax file ?
 The following code is throwing an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
    string cookyval = "";
    try
    {
        cookyval = Context.Request.Cookies["parentPageName"].Value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cookyval = "";
    }
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Session_End event is fired by the IIS worker process, not an HTTP request.  Therefore your HttpContext will be null and you won't be able to set a client's cookie.

Comment: More than this, the link now triggers Symantec Endpoint Protection

Comment: Removed the dead link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible.

The request is no longer alive at the point the Session_End fires.

Sorry,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Session_End isn't run in the context of a user request, so there's no access to cookies (or any other request variables).

If you put the value into Session, I think you can access that:

```
string cookyval = "";
try
{
    cookyval = (string)Session["parentPageName"];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cookyval = "";
}
```

Otherwise, you'd need to write it to some other server side storage (like a database).